# Ckfinder duplicate assembly error in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to add ckfinder to ckeditor for uploading image. When I first built my project I got a System.Web.UI error, and added System.Design from .NET to references. That solved the first error but this time I get:

```
Error   14  Duplicate 'AssemblyCompany' attribute   C:\Users\Projects\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication6\MvcApplication6\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs  11  12  MvcApplication6
```

How can I fix this error ?

Answer (score 2):

Exclude all CkFinder assemblies from project, then you can run project.

Comment: I found the answer you know I asked this question long time ago :) But thanks anyway

Comment: does this prevent you from even using ckfinder then?

Answer (score 0):

For any with this problem check if you included in your project an folder that is an project too.